# Flutter: Identify if there are documents in a firebase collection

Tags: firebase, flutter, dart, google-cloud-firestore

I want to post data to a series of collections and documents one within the other,

```
CollectionReference data = FirebaseFirestore.instance
        .collection('Data')
        .doc(user)
        .collection('First')
        .doc(category)
        .collection(time);
```

```
data.add({'element': 'field'});
```

but when I try to do it, the names of the dynamic names appear in italics, it would not be a problem if it were only a variation of the font style, the problem is that when I try to know if there is data in the collection `First` it shows me that there is nothing

```
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return StreamBuilder(
      stream: FirebaseFirestore.instance
          .collection('Data')
          .doc(user)
          .collection('First')
          .snapshots(),
      builder: (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot<QuerySnapshot> snapshot) {
        if (snapshot.hasData) {
          print(snapshot.data);
          return Icon(Icons.check);
        }
        return Icon(Icons.error);
      },
    );
  }
```

> flutter: null

It is necessary to separate by first, second, third, etc and each of these must have separate different categories and in each category must have its time

Firebase looks like this

> Data  ->  *S6W4kb1dKycD060v47FFs0i528Q2*  ->  First  ->  *post*  ->  19:00

Only if I add an item directly from the Firebase console does it recognize that items exist

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your call fragment...

```
CollectionReference data = FirebaseFirestore.instance
        .collection('Data')
        .doc(user)
        .collection('First')
        .doc(category)
        .collection(time);
```

...**NONE** of the `.collection()` and `.doc()` create *anything* - they are just extending the refPath of the underlying reference i.e. `Data/{user}/First/{category}/time` is the collection you will add to.  When you **FINALLY** execute `data.add({'element': 'field'})` a **SINGLE** document with contents (and unspecified Id) `{'element': 'field'}` is added.

It is helpful to remember that in Firestore, "collections" are not a physical identity; they are a convenient part of a structured path to a document.  For example, in

```
TopLevel/document1/NextLevel/document2/NextNextLevel/document3/NextNextNextLevel/actualDocument
```

**NONE OF** TopLevel, document1, NextLevel, document2, NextNextLevel, document3, or NextNextNextLevel need to exist - which is why they show in italics in the console.

Comment: thanks, so what can I do if I need that same tree or at least a similar one? how can I make them exist?

Comment: If you want those documents to exist, you'll need to write data to each of them individually. So `FirebaseFirestore.instance
        .collection('Data')
        .doc(user).set(...)`, `FirebaseFirestore.instance
        .collection('Data')
        .doc(user)
        .collection('First')
        .doc(category).set(...)`, etc

Comment: More important question: **DO** you actually need them to exist?  The structured path to the one document still exists, and to any other document you create similarly; the indexes will still be created; your documents will still be organized.  The presence, or lack of presence, of documents and collections "up the tree" has no performance impact whatever.